Ability replacing power combined with baseline powers
The Solid Form power states

While in this form, you can substitute your
Power rank for your Might and Toughness...

The Strike power has a baseline of Might
I was wondering whether the baseline of Strike will be replaced with my Solid form's rank when in Solid form, or is my Strike always based of my Might, regardless of which form I am in?

Not an answer, just a comment as how I'm currently ruling it because I haven't found out for sure. When activating Solid Form, Might is altered and with it Strike. It cannot exceed the Trait cap.
